# Android gradle test with robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm using AndroidStudio and build with gradle.

I want to test my app with Robolectirc, so I add below in build.gradle

buildscript's dependencies section:

`classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.+'`

Apply the android-test plugin:

`apply plugin: 'android-test'`

Add test-only dependencies using the testCompile configuration:

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
```

> These are from https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin

so I added these stuff, I get gradle.build like below.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'

    classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 17
}

signingConfigs {
    freeConfing {
        storeFile file("../../../workspace_android/keystore/pm.keystore");
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "key"
        keyPassword "password"
    }
    paidConfing {
        storeFile file("../../../workspace_android/keystore/pm.keystore");
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "key"
        keyPassword "password"
    }
}

productFlavors {
            paid {
                packageName "com.my.app"
                buildConfig "public final static boolean isFullVersion = true;"
                versionCode 2
                versionName "1.0.0"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.paidConfing
            }
            free {
                packageName "com.my.app"
                buildConfig "public final static boolean isFullVersion = false;"
                versionCode 2
                versionName "1.0.0"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.freeConfing
            }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

I want to test my app so, I typed in terminal like

`gradle test`

but, I got

`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:testFreeDebug'.`

The product flavor name is changed `testFreeDebug`

and `gradle tasks` also not working...

Before I didn't add test stuff, it was good working.

How can I test my app with robolectric?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the latest snapshot of the plugin.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

Comment: also use `gradle check` instead of `gradle test`